# My many-to-many relationship does not return needed Users Roles

Tags: php, laravel

I created a many to many relationship between Role and User models. They have a pivot table called `role_user`. It consists of `id`, `user_id`, and `role_id`.

My user model has this relationship:

```
public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
}
```

and this function:

```
public function hasRole($role){
   return null !== $this->roles()->where("name", $role)->first();
}
```

I am trying to make my PostPolicy class, before function checking if user is admin or Super Admin

```
public function before(User $user){
    if($user->hasRole('Admin') || $user->hasRole('Super Admin') ){
        return true ;
    }
}
```

And the function comes back with the response false, however I am logged in with the user which has a role Admin.

My roles table:

```
id
name
description
created_at
updated_at
```

Users:

```
id
name
email
email_verified_at
password
remember_token
created_at
updated_at
```

Comment: Is this spatie by any chance? Regarding naming, I would write any roles as lower case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I write your code and attach roles then it start to work:

```
$user->roles()->attach($roleName);
```

I also add `return false` under `if` in `PostPolicy@before` method) - here is working [example](https://implode.io/KWLKmP)

Answer (score 0):

Do you also have a users function set on the Roles Model?

I believe you must have both for the many to many to work correctly in Laravel.

Comment: I do have a function for the roles model